# resources.GetObject("$this.Icon") crashes application on Windows XP

Tags: c#, exception, resources, windows-xp

I've made this program which works fine in Windows 7, but it doesn't seem to work in Windows XP, as it crashed right away with a 'Program has closed bla bla send error report' message from Windows.
After some googling I found a solution to get myself an exceptionlog in the Event Log.
This is the result:

**Edit: new exception log (with unhandled exception filter)**

> **Exception: Het doel van een aanroep heeft een uitzondering veroorzaakt.** 
>   bij System.RuntimeMethodHandle._SerializationInvoke(Object target,
>   SignatureStruct& declaringTypeSig, SerializationInfo info,
>   StreamingContext context)    bij
>   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.SerializationInvoke(Object target,
>   SignatureStruct declaringTypeSig, SerializationInfo info,
>   StreamingContext context)    bij
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.SerializationInvoke(Object
>   target, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)    bij
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.CompleteISerializableObject(Object
>   obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)    bij
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.FixupSpecialObject(ObjectHolder
>   holder)    bij System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.DoFixups()
>   bij
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler
>   handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean
>   isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)    bij
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream
>   serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean
>   isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)    bij
>   System.Resources.ResourceReader.DeserializeObject(Int32 typeIndex)
>   bij System.Resources.ResourceReader.LoadObjectV2(Int32 pos,
>   ResourceTypeCode& typeCode)    bij
>   System.Resources.ResourceReader.LoadObject(Int32 pos,
>   ResourceTypeCode& typeCode)    bij
>   System.Resources.RuntimeResourceSet.GetObject(String key, Boolean
>   ignoreCase, Boolean isString)    bij
>   System.Resources.RuntimeResourceSet.GetObject(String key, Boolean
>   ignoreCase)    bij System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(String
>   name, CultureInfo culture, Boolean wrapUnmanagedMemStream)    bij
>   System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(String name)    bij
>   STREDIT.frmMain.InitializeComponent()    bij STREDIT.frmMain..ctor()
>   bij STREDIT.Program.Main()

I've found the place where it crashed:

```
this.Controls.Add(this.statusStrip1);
this.Controls.Add(this.menuStrip1);
this.Icon = ((System.Drawing.Icon)(resources.GetObject("$this.Icon"))); // Here
this.MainMenuStrip = this.menuStrip1;
this.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(726, 220);
```

Does anyone have an idea why this happens?

Thanks in advance

Comment: That is just the stack trace. If you want the full exception I would suggest using AppDomain.UnhandledException to get the exception that crashes your program. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx

Comment: I've done that now, High. I don't see any difference though.

Comment: You forgot to log the exception's InnerException property.  Use e.ExceptionObject.ToString() in your event handler.  Shooting off the hip, you probably used an icon format that XP doesn't support.

Comment: It was indeed the icon type. Windows XP didn't like it. Thanks Hans!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows XP does not support PNG icons. Create a non-PNG ico for the application, and the application will run fine :).

Answer (score 1):

Icon type correct or not, there is a solution to handle it correctly:

- put the icons into Assembly's resource file (if you haven't)
- access the icon like this:

  ```
  this.Icon = global::AEM.UI.Properties.Resources.your_icon_name;
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same symptoms on Win7 (with a ICO image) and I found a workaround : add a small delay before the `InitializeComponent()` for let time to the app to load resources.

```
public MyForm()
{
    Thread.Sleep(100); // delay for loading ressources

    InitializeComponent();
}
```

In my case is was not caused by the image format because it worked fine with that image during months of development. It was really caused by the resources loader.